# C# DataGridView how to limit multi selection to same column only?

Tags: c#, datagridview

as i'm stuck on my Problem i had to ask you for help. I have a DataGridView where i wanna select multiple rows but only in the same column. If the user is outside the column he started the selection in, i want to prevent that this rows would also been selected.

How can i do that?

With Kind Regards

Ralf

Comment: Each row has many columns, so your question is pretty unclear.  If you allow multiple rows, by definition that means multiple columns

Comment: Let's make it easier to understand. You have 3 columns. Selection should be able in every column. But when you begin selecting let's say in column 2, then only the rows in column 2 should be able to select. So if you start in column 2, column 1 and 3 should be ignored... You can select every row in column 2 but not in the other both. Same if you start at column 1. Then 2 and 3 should not be able to select.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add CellClick event handler to automatically remove selection of unwanted column

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 1) {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = false;
    }}
```

Downside: you unable to select other column

Comment: tried - doesn't work like what i expected. but thanks anyway.